# Are object variables pointers in Java?

Tags: java, android, oop, object

Are object variables pointers?  If I declare an object variable and then assign another object to it, do I have one object or two?

Specifically what I need to do is in Android, I want to capture a location object and set it aside to compare to the next location object that comes along.

Comment: In Java, the term is "reference," not "pointer," though you can think of them as basically the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one object, with two references. Specifically,

```
int[] a = {1, 2};
int[] b = a;
a[0] = 17;
System.out.println(b[0]); // 17
```

You would need to explicitly clone an object (if it is `Cloneable`) or copy its contents in some other way to create a non-shared new instance.

Comment: thank you, that's what I thought but I thought I heard at one point that java doesn't have pointers so wasn't sure how that would work

Comment: It doesn't have pointers as one understands them in C - there is no pointer arythmetic, for one thing. Everything is dealt with transparently. You never need to dereference a reference. References are pointers made safe.

Comment: I'll have to check it complete in a few minutes it won't let me know.  May I ask a follow up here or should I post this seperate?  I can figure this out easily enough but if you know...in android when I receive a location object, and then the location is updated is it the same object or a new object?

Comment: Sorry, I answered a Java question, I have no clue about Android platform :P

Comment: i see, thank you for clarifying...so if I create an object reference it won't get rid of that object till I'm done with it, correct?

Comment: Objects are garbage-collected; if there is no way to access the object any more, it will automagically disappear. No action is needed on the programmer's part. That means, if you put an object into a local variable and never store it anywhere else, it will be forgotten some time after you exited the local scope.

Comment: no worries regarding android, I'll figure that out :)  thanks for your help in understanding this :)